# Are non-web safe fonts safe to use?

Tags: web-fonts

I would like to use DIN Engschrift as a headline font on my website, however it is not a web-safe font and does not appear as desired on different browser and operating system combinations.

How safe is it to use a font like Would DIN Condensed by ParaType?

Comment: Is your question more so "what is a web safe font?" or rather "is it safe to use a non-web safe font?"

Comment: What I meant was - would it be safe to use 'DIN Condensed' even if it is not a web-safe font?

Comment: I edited your post to hopefully better reflect your question. Please feel free to edit it again if it's not what you're asking

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not a web safe font because it is not installed on a majority of user's systems (the definition of web safe fonts).

That doesn't mean that you shouldn't use it though. It just means that you need to import it (in your HTML using `<link/>` using or CSS `@import` - [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12380004/2065702) talks about the difference). But you should provide fall back fonts that are more supported, such as

```
font-family: "Din Condensed", Sans-Serif;
/* Sans-Serif here falls back to Helvetica for Macs and Arial for Windows */
```